# Use Observable for a one time event

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have 2 functions ( for simplicity, open/close ):

```
open(config){
    ...do something
    this.watchForClosing = Observable.create(..?..)
    return this.watchForClosing
}

close(closeArgs){
    this.watchForClosing.complete(closeArgs)
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is a calling method that works like this:

```
myClass.open(myData)
.subscribe( closeArgs => console.log('closed'))
```

Basically I want the calling function to call the **open** function and get a 'callback' when the **close** function has been called, and am struggling on how to create an Observable that will do this. thanks for any guidance !

Comment: What is you question? You don't know how to use `Observable.create()` or what?

Comment: Yea, what type of Observable could I create here?  Observable.of or Observable.from don't seem to fit my needs. is there an 'operator' that can use to  create an observable where all i really need to 'next' is a completion ?

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: I was able to do something like

```
class myClass {
    constructor(){
    this.observer = null
}
   open(componentConfig){
        return Observable.create(obs => {
            this.observer = obs
        })
    }

close(closeArgs){
        this.observer.next(closeArgs)
        this.observer.complete()
    }
```

}

sorry if was original question was too vague